# Swiftui remove swipe to delete functionality

Tags: list, swiftui, edit

Is there a way to remove or deactivate swipe to delete functionality that remove items only per edit button?

Comment: @Yrb You should take a closer look at the question.

Comment: Yep, you are right. . . I COMPLETELY misread that one. That's what I get for doing this at the end of the day...

Comment: If my answer from last week helped, you can accept the answer so it easier for people to find this question in the future. (also you get some bonus reputation)

Answer (score 3):

You can limit the delete functionality of a `List`/`Form` depending on the `EditMode` state, by using [`deleteDisabled(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/gaugestyleconfiguration/maximumvaluelabel-swift.struct/deletedisabled(_:)).

The following is a short example demonstrating deleting which only works in edit mode:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var data = Array(1 ... 10)
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                DataRows(data: $data)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Delete Test")
            .toolbar {
                EditButton()
            }
        }
    }
}


struct DataRows: View {
    
    @Environment(\.editMode) private var editMode
    @Binding private var data: [Int]
    
    init(data: Binding<[Int]>) {
        _data = data
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(data, id: \.self) { item in
            Text("Item: \(item)")
        }
        .onMove { indices, newOffset in
            data.move(fromOffsets: indices, toOffset: newOffset)
        }
        .onDelete { indexSet in
            data.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
        }
        .deleteDisabled(editMode?.wrappedValue != .active)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm, looks like this does not work for iOS 16 anymore, at least for the Beta. All elements stay undeletable, even in edit mode.

Comment: @Thomas Are you sure you have the `onDelete` modifier added? If this exact code in entirety doesn’t work, then yeah - likely a bug.

Comment: Yes, just checked again. @George Don't know if it's a bug or will not work in iOS 16 anymore....

Comment: @Thomas You're right - very likely a bug somewhere with the updating of the `deleteDisabled` modifier, because the `editMode` is still updating appropriately

Comment: This bug is very strange. I have made a custom edit button for testing purposes. It toggles a bool binding `cellsDeletable` and after a few seconds also changes the environment editMode to `.active`. The form rows / cells observe the state of the cellsDeletable value via `.deleteDisabled(!cellsDeletable)`.  During the time where the cellsDeletable is set to True and editMode hasn't yet been set to .active the cells can be deleted by a swipe. However as soon as the editMode is changed, the cells can't be deleted anymore.

Comment: Somehow I found a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73704545/swiftui-deletedisabled-is-not-working-as-expected/75678446#75678446)